# define scaffold dropdown array in model cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'd like to define some default values in my model and the scaffolding within my controller use those values to populate a dropdown list rather than just having it automatically create an input field.  I know I could bake my view, etc but I'd like to keep everything as flexible as possible for now.

Any ideas on how to set the values from my model onto the scaffolded view?

Comment: Don't use scaffolding. Use bake and your custom templates and maybe [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) for some dropdowns.